# When my managers call to US phone number, client see incoming call as "Unknown name" from twilio app

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Can i fix my problems and what wrong in my code?

Problems

1. i use application for call to my clients from twilio number
   When my managers call to US phone number, client see incoming call as "Unknown name"
2. When my manager calls - silence before connect to client in browser
   Then client accepts call - and all ok

Server code

```
generateToken: () {
    let clientName = 'twilio_agent';
    let _id = req.body._id;
    let phoneno = req.body.phoneno;

    //
    realmsProvider.get({_id: _id})
    .then(data => {
        if (!data) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Account not found with _id:'+ _id });
        }

        var capability = new ClientCapability({
            accountSid: data.sid,
            authToken: data.authToken,
            ttl: config.twilio.ttl
        });

        capability.addScope(
          new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
                applicationSid: data.application.sid,
                clientName: data.name,
                callerId: phoneno
          }));

        // incoming call
        if (phoneno != null) {
            capability.addScope(
                new ClientCapability.IncomingClientScope(phoneno));
        }
        else {
            capability.addScope(
                new ClientCapability.IncomingClientScope(clientName));
        }

        var token = capability.toJwt();

        return res.status(200).json({ token: token });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return utils.handleError(res, err);
    });
}

voice: () {
    let phoneNumber = req.body.PhoneNumber;
    let callerId = req.body.CallerId;
    let twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    let dial = twiml.dial({
        //https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial
        answerOnBridge: true,
        //phone number from
        callerId : callerId,

        //record all calls
        record: 'record-from-answer-dual'
    });

    if (phoneNumber != null) {
        dial.number(phoneNumber);
    }

    dial.client(callerId.replace(/\+/, ''));

    res.type('text/xml');

    res.send(twiml.toString());
}
```

Browser code

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, {
    debug: true,
    enableRingingState: true,
    sounds: {
        incoming: 'URL-TO-MP3.mp3',
        outgoing: 'URL-TO-MP3.mp3',
        dtmf8: 'URL-TO-MP3.mp3'
    }
});

function call(currentPhoneno, phoneTo, companyNameInTwilio) {
    $scope.calling = 1;

    if (!validatePhoneno(phoneTo)) {
        growl.error('Bad phone number');
        return;
    }

    var connection = Twilio.Device.connect({ // Connect our call.
        CallerId: currentPhoneno, // Your Twilio number (Format: +15556667777).
        PhoneNumber: phoneTo, // Number to call (Format: +15556667777).
        From: companyNameInTwilio
    });

    connection.on('ringing', function(hasEarlyMedia) {
        // some code for ringing
    });
}
```

Comment: this might be what you are looking for the "Unknown name" problem ,m https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180148-Displaying-a-business-name-or-custom-text-as-Caller-ID